# typedef'd type not visible as return type of a member function

Tags: c++, scope, typedef

This program fails to compile(using gcc-4.5). The error message says:

error: ‘myType_t’ does not name a type

```
  1 class abc{
  2 //typedef int myType_t;
  3 
  4   public:
  5 typedef int myType_t;
  6 
  7     abc();
  8     myType_t fun1();
  9 };
 10 
 11 myType_t abc::fun1()
 12 {
 13   return 0;
 14 }
 15 
 16 int main()
 17 {
 18   abc abc1;
 19   return 0;
 20 }
```

Now declaring `typedef int myType_t;` outside the class `abc` makes this compile.
My confusion is, what is the problem if the return type of a member function is typedef'd inside the class.

Comment: Next time you post some code, better remove the line numbers first. The code as you have it is not a proper testcase.

Comment: alrite, the problem is the `vi` editor where line numbers also get copied. i'll take care of this from the next time.

Comment: @Aditya: proper test case: Code that I can copy into my compiler and compile with no changes.  See what happens when I copy this? http://www.ideone.com/I60DW

Comment: Isn't this being a little bit pedantic?

Comment: Pedantic or not, it's actually good idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the C++ Standard:

***9.9  Nested type names*** ***[class.nested.type]***

*Type names obey exactly the same scope rules as other names.In particular, type names defined within a class definition cannot be used outside their class without qualification.*

```
class X {
public :
   typedef int I;
   class Y { /  . . .  / };
   I a;
};

I b;            // error
Y c;            // error
X::Y d;         // OK
X::I e;         // OK
```

So You need to access it as:

```
abc::myType_t abc::fun1()
```

Answer (score 7):

This is because of a quirk in C++ syntax.

Because the member function's class is only precised at the moment where the name of the function itself is declared, anything before that must spell it out fully.

```
ReturnType
ClassName
::             // only here do we enter the scope 'ClassName'
FunctionName
(
  ArgumentType0,
  ArgumentType1,
  ...
) {
}
```

This can be overcomed using C++0x late return type syntax

```
auto
ClassName
::
FunctionName
(
  ArgumentType0,
  ArgumentType1,
  ...
)
->
ReturnType
{
}
```

Because it postpones the declaration of the return type long enough to enter the scope (it also allows to declare it based on the arguments of the function, using `decltype` for example).

Answer (score 6):

```
myType_t abc::fun1()
```

Since `myType_t` is a nested type, so you've to write this :

```
  abc::myType_t  abc::fun1()
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^note this!
```

`abc::` tells the compiler that `myType_t` is defined inside the class `abc`. You write `abc::myType_t` just in the same way you write `abc::fun1()`. But inside the class, you don't need to write`abc::`, neither for `myType_t`, nor for `fun1()`.