# Using typedef types in definition

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, templates, class-template

I have a class as follows,

```
template<size_t N>
class A 
{
   typedef int(*ARRAY)[N];
   array getArray();

   ARRAY array;
};
```

Then how can I use the type `ARRAY` in the definition? I have tried this

```
template<size_t N>
ARRAY A<N>::getArray()
{
   return array;
}
```

But, it tells me that `ARRAY` is not defined.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: `typedef int (*ARRAY)[N];`

Comment: @BillLynch that's named `A<N>::ARRAY`, as you very well know from your response.

Comment: @Blindy: It feels petty to say they didn't define `ARRAY`, if what one really means is that you didn't give the right scope accessors to `ARRAY`.

Comment: `ARRAY A<N>::getArray()` Before you say the function is a member of `A<N>`, how do you expect the compiler to know where `ARRAY` is defined? It just reads from left to right. You can use a trailing return type to avoid the repetition: `auto A<N>::getArray() -> ARRAY`. But please don't use `ALL_CAPS` for anything except macros, and don't use macros.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typedef'd type not visible as return type of a member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960778/typedefd-type-not-visible-as-return-type-of-a-member-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ARRAY` is depended name, therefor you need to use the [`typename` keyword before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600936/officially-what-is-typename-for) it, outside the class scope.

```
template<size_t N>
typename A<N>::ARRAY A<N>::getArray()
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
   return array;
}
```

or using [trailing return](https://arne-mertz.de/2016/11/trailing-return-types-everywhere/)

```
template<size_t N>
auto A<N>::getArray() -> ARRAY
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
   return array;
}
```

In addition, you have a typo in your class member declaration. The

```
array getArray();
```

should be

```
ARRAY getArray();
```

However, is there any reason that you do not want to use the [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array)?

Answer (score 3):

The problems is that you haven't defined a type `ARRAY` in the namespace, but rather within the scope of the class template. As such, the unqualified lookup doesn't find a type by that name.

Besides using a qualified name to refer to this member type alias as shown in Bill Lynch's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63118189/2079303), another way is to use a trailing return type in which case the name is looked up within the context of the class:

```
template<size_t N>
auto A<N>::getArray() -> ARRAY {
    return array;
}
```

---

P.S. I recommend highly against obfuscating the pointerness (or referenceness) of types by defining type aliases  unless the alias is used in generic programming where it might be replaced by a fancy pointer (or proxy reference). In such cases the alias should conventionally be named to signify that it is a "pointer" (or "reference") such as for example in the case of type aliases of iterators and allocators and their type traits in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<size_t N>
typename A<N>::ARRAY A<N>::getArray(){
    return array;
}
```

https://repl.it/repls/DecisiveFragrantFact

Comment: Alternatively, `auto A<N>::getArray() -> ARRAY` also works, and is a bit less noisy